# Adding specific class in respect of space and position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using double sided timeline in my website. On both sides of the timeline bar there are several thumbnails. I have added `on-left-track` class on left thumbnails and `on-right-track` class on right thumbnail. `on-left-track` class has `float:left` and `on-right-track` class has `float:right`. First will be `on-left-track` and 2nd will be `on-right-track`; 3rd will be again `on-left-track`.

### My questions are

1) I want to add `on-left-track` and `on-right-track` through jQuery.

2) As there is a `float` on both, if one thumb is small in height the next of the next goes there to fill the space. i.e: I have normal thumb on `left` and next is small thumb on `right` and the very next of the second which should be `on left` goes on right.

### My code e.g:

```
<div class="thumb on-left-track>
  ....
</div>
<div class="thumb on-right-track>
  ....
</div>

<div class="thumb on-left-track>
  ....
</div>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: So is it possible to have two consecutive thumb `on-left-track` and the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

For first question:

```
$( "div:odd").attr('class','on-left-track');
$( "div:even").attr('class','on-right-track');

// Or:
// $( "div:odd").addClass('on-left-track');
// $( "div:even").addClass('on-right-track');
```

Comment: The odd and even order **does not always** determine the position of the thumbnail.

Comment: He said he wanted to add right and left dynamically jquery for first question

Comment: Though he also provided [_a tricky_] condition on his second question

Comment: A fiddle will be better to know the problem better

Comment: Yep. I agree. A sample fiddle will do.

Answer (score 0):

Then do this on your `css`:

```
.thumb.on-left-track { float: left }
.thumb.on-right-track { float: right }
```

Of course, this answer *doesn't* consider the other `css` styles that may override these styles.